# PHP records not inserted to database using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

here is the AJAX request body

**Ajax**

```
var date = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
var text=this.value;
var id=1;
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "StoreMessages.php" ,
data: { room: id, msg:text,sendat:date }
});
```

**PHP Code**

```
 if(isset($_GET['room']))
        {
            $chatroom_name = $_GET['room'];

            if(isset($_GET['msg']))
            {
                $text= $_GET['msg'] ;
                if(isset($_GET['sendat']))
                {
                    $local_time= $_GET['sendat']);
                    insertMessage( $text,$local_time, $chatroom_name);
                } 
            } 
        } 


function insertMessage($message_body,$local_time,$room_id)
{


    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message_body');</script>";


    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$local_time');</script>";


    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$room_id');</script>";

    $conn = new mysqli($GLOBALS['server'], $GLOBALS['user'], $GLOBALS['pass'], $GLOBALS['db_name']);

    if($conn==false)
        {
            die("unable to connect database");
        }

    $sql="INSERT INTO `message` (`Message_Text`, `Time`, `Conversation_Id`) VALUES ('$message_body', '$local_time', '$room_id')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        echo "record inserted successfully"."<br/>";

    }
    else{
        echo "error".mysqli_error($db_conn);
    }
```

**Explanation**

ajax call triggers when user typed message and hit enter key ajax data field variable contains value i checked then by setting alert when i checked the the data field variables value by setting alert in php code there only text variable contain value and alertbox didn't appears for other variables acutally i am trying to store live chat to database

Comment: Could you add some punctuation to that explanation text please?

Comment: @Jeto sorry for that if you understand my issue then please help me

Comment: @user3783243 i'm new to php i didn't work before on this i don't know how to solve it i have values in variables before ajax code triggers and in php file when i get values it seems only text variable contains the values others are blank also i have no idea to to return response from php and also how to debug the response

Comment: @user3783243 check this <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected ')' in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\ChatRoom\StoreMessages.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br /

Comment: @user3783243  get parse error at **sendAt** BECAUSE i sent the time in this format ( 05:23:12 )

Comment: @user3783243 thanks for tip  to debug it worked

Answer (score 1):

The first step to debugging this is is/was diagnosing where the failure occurred. To do this:

1. Open your developer console
2. Go to the `network` tab
3. Make whatever action triggers the AJAX request
4. Click the request that appears in the `network` tab
5. Go to the `response` tab*

*If the status code of the request is a 500 that also is an indication that the script is failing on the PHP side. Go to the server and look at the error logs.

From the response we got in the `response` tab we identify the issue to be the trailing closing parenthesis on this line:

```
$local_time= $_GET['sendat']);
```

Additionally you should use parameterized queries. A single quote in any of the fields will break your query.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Roughly:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `message` (`Message_Text`, `Time`, `Conversation_Id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

Then `prepare` that, `bind` the values, and `execute` the query.

Also I'd send back a JSON object rather than JS code. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php.